# How do I create .exe in Android app?

Tags: android, mobile, nokia

I want to know how I create .exe file in Android. How do I run in Android mobile any new software required in Android mobile?

Is it possible to convert my Android app into a Nokia app or app for any other OS?

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, the english is a little off, sorry dude. Can you rephrase the question at all?

Comment: android apps have .apk extension and are entirely different from .exe files. Not sure what you're asking though, to be fair.

Comment: Do you mean [porting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting)?? (Wikipedia is down thanks to the US congress, but it basically defines what porting is)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm going to answer what I **think** you're asking.

You cannot create an exe file FROM WITHIN an android app (as far as I'm aware). You would need a Windows architecture in order to create exe files. I'm sure there is probably some hacky way to do this from Linux, but I'm not sure if this would be compatible or useable, on an Android handset.

If you're asking how do you create an executable file for your Android app (e.g. I have build an Android app, how do I go about creating an executable file?) then thats different. Android apps aren't .exe files. They have the extension .apk. Creating an Android apk is very easy. Right click on your project in Eclipse and select "Export for" and choose Android - go through the process (which is very straightforwards) and it will produce an apk file for you.

Your second question is whether you can convert your android app into a nokia app or app for another phone OS. The short answer here is NO. The long answer is that the different mobile OSs use completely different SDKs and architectures for their apps. There is no reliable way (yet) to port apps between OSs. There are a few frameworks which allow you to create cross platform compatible apps which you can look into. Appcelerator's Titanium is probably the best of the lot.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The executable files in android are **.apk files** . You can install only .apk files in android mobile. You can install softwares from **Android market** or directly if you have some apk files.

Go through the link to know more : [create-apk-files-for-android-phone](http://www.technobitez.com/how-to/create-apk-files-for-android-phone)  &  [install-apk-files-on-android](http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/beginner/install-apk-files-on-android/#.)